# Why simple SQL count takes longer while all update,delete,insert possible thru SQL Server Engine only

Tags: sql-server, count

I see NO way to update, delete, insert record into a table directly without SQL Server engine.
Also SQL Server engine clearly knows any change in table.

But even simple `Select Count(*) from tblTableName` takes longer. It does not look like the SQL Server engine maintains the counter and updates during every change occurs into a table.

Every time, it starts some processing in the background to know the count from even single table though indexed. What does it do... why not counter flag maintained?

Example :

```
Select count(*) from Bills
Select count(*) from Claims
```

Comment: Jes Schultz Borland did a good blog post on this issue on Brent Ozar Unlimited a couple of months ago.  http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/count-number-rows-table-sql-server/

Comment: If you use `COUNT(*)`, **YOU** are telling SQL Server to go count all rows in the table. So it will do that. You can speed things up by **(a)** having an index on a narrow, non-nullable column (that can be used to do the counting), or **(b)** by inspecting the catalog views for an approximation (rather than going out to count the accurate number of rows) if that's good enough for you

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is such info stored at index level: `[see rows column in sys.indexes][1]`.

You could interrogate that table instead.

Some clues that would make that counter usefulness:

- What about the case SELECT count(*) FROM Bills WHERE id_paid = 1?
- What if the SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bills needs less resources than querying sys.indexes table?
- The counter should be updated every time some are deleted from table. Wouldn't be this an overhead, taking into account the [statistics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/statistics-in-sql-server/) have to be also updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the absolutely up-to-date, accurate numbers, you can inspect the **catalog views** of SQL Server which keep track of the number of rows in table (what you called the *counter flag*) - more or less. On a really busy system with thousands of concurrent users, this number might be not accurate at all times - but for most cases, it's quite good enough, and it doesn't go out and actually **count** the rows - so it's really fast:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```